# Can I assign any SSH key permission for specific repository on bit bucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have many `teams` created in my **Bitbucket** account. Every team has some `repositories` created in it which are deployed on different servers. For pulling the repository, I need to add public `ssh keys` of the server to my Bitbucket account. But that means anyone on the server can take a pull from any of my Bit bucket repositories. Is there a work around? If not what security measure should I take to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [deployment keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-deployment-keys-294486051.html) are for:

> You can use deployment keys with your Bitbucket Cloud repositories. A deployment key grants read-only access to a public or private repository. With a deployment key a user or a process can pull or clone a repository over SSH. Deployment keys have the following features and limitations:
>
> - Deployment keys do not apply to your plan limit.
> - You can add the same deployment key to multiple repositories.
> - The deployment key must be unique — it cannot also be associated with an account.
>
> Deployment keys are useful for authenticating a build server to checkout and test your code.